# MVVM async await pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, async-await

I've been trying to write an MVVM screen for a WPF application, using the async & await keywords to write asynchronous methods for 1. Initially loading data, 2. Refreshing the data, 3. Saving changes and then refreshing. Although I have this working, the code is very messy and I can't help thinking that there must be a better implementation. Can anyone advise on a simpler implementation?

This is a cut-down version of my ViewModel:

```
public class ScenariosViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ScenariosViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await SaveAsync());
        RefreshCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await LoadDataAsync());
    }

    public async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
        IsLoading = true; //synchronously set the busy indicator flag
        await Task.Run(() => Scenarios = _service.AllScenarios())
            .ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                IsLoading = false;
                if (t.Exception != null)
                {
                    throw t.Exception; //Allow exception to be caught on Application_UnhandledException
                }
            });
    }

    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
    private async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        IsLoading = true; //synchronously set the busy indicator flag
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _service.Save(_selectedScenario);
            LoadDataAsync(); // here we get compiler warnings because not called with await
        }).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.Exception != null)
            {
                throw t.Exception;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

IsLoading is exposed to the view where it is bound to a busy indicator.

LoadDataAsync is called by the navigation framework when the screen is first viewed, or when a refresh button is pressed. This method should synchronously set IsLoading, then return control to the UI thread until the service has returned the data. Finally throwing any exceptions so they can be caught by the global exception handler (not up for discussion!).

SaveAync is called by a button, passing updated values from a form to the service. It should synchronously set IsLoading, asynchronously call the Save method on the service and then trigger a refresh.

Comment: Did you check this out? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx.

Comment: Yes, it's a great article. I'm not sure I like binding to Something.Result though, feel like the ViewModel should be making it's state more obvious than that.

Comment: Just an idea to try... Make a standard getter only property and in the get await for Something. Bind using IsAsync=true.

Comment: If you want help on improving working code, [codereview.se]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are a few problems in the code that jump out to me:

- Usage of `ContinueWith`. `ContinueWith` is a dangerous API (it has a surprising default value for its `TaskScheduler`, so it should really only be used if you specify a `TaskScheduler`). It's also just plain awkward compared to the equivalent `await` code.
- Setting `Scenarios` from a thread pool thread. I always follow the guideline in my code that data-bound VM properties are treated as part of the UI and must only be accessed from the UI thread. There are exceptions to this rule (particularly on WPF), but they're not the same on every MVVM platform (and are a questionable design to begin with, IMO), so I just treat VMs as part of the UI layer.
- Where the exceptions are thrown. According to the comment, you want exceptions raised to `Application.UnhandledException`, but I don't think this code will do that. Assuming `TaskScheduler.Current` is `null` at the start of `LoadDataAsync`/`SaveAsync`, then the re-raising exception code will actually raise the exception on a *thread pool* thread, not the *UI* thread, thus sending it to `AppDomain.UnhandledException` rather than `Application.UnhandledException`.
- How the exceptions are re-thrown. You'll lose your stack trace.
- Calling `LoadDataAsync` without an `await`. With this simplified code, it'll probably work, but it does introduce the possibility of ignoring unhandled exceptions. In particular, if any of the synchronous part of `LoadDataAsync` throws, then that exception would be silently ignored.

Instead of messing around with the manual-exception-rethrows, I recommend just using the more natural approach of exception propagation through `await`:

- If an asynchronous operation fails, the task gets an exception placed on it.
- `await` will examine this exception, and re-raise it in a proper way (preserving the original stack trace).
- `async void` methods do not have a task on which to place an exception, so they will re-raise it directly on their `SynchronizationContext`. In this case, since your `async void` methods run on the UI thread, the exception will be sent to `Application.UnhandledException`.

(the `async void` methods I'm referring to are the `async` delegates passed to `DelegateCommand`).

The code now becomes:

```
public class ScenariosViewModel : BindableBase
{
  public ScenariosViewModel()
  {
    SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await SaveAsync());
    RefreshCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await LoadDataAsync());
  }

  public async Task LoadDataAsync()
  {
    IsLoading = true;
    try
    {
      Scenarios = await Task.Run(() => _service.AllScenarios());
    }
    finally
    {
      IsLoading = false;
    }
  }

  private async Task SaveAsync()
  {
    IsLoading = true;
    await Task.Run(() => _service.Save(_selectedScenario));
    await LoadDataAsync();
  }
}
```

Now all the problems have been resolved:

- `ContinueWith` has been replaced with the more appropriate `await`.
- `Scenarios` is set from the UI thread.
- All exceptions are propagated to `Application.UnhandledException` rather than `AppDomain.UnhandledException`.
- Exceptions maintain their original stack trace.
- There are no un-`await`-ed tasks, so all exceptions will be observed some way or another.

And the code is cleaner, too. IMO. :)

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you for such a complete answer. This is a great improvement on my code.

Comment: The LoadDataAsync method is actually on a base class I use for my ViewModels, which calls an abstract method loadData which calls a specific service and sets a specific property. Is there any way I can retain this and still set properties on UI Thread?

    protected abstract void loadData();
    protected virtual async Task loadDataAsync()
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            loadData();
            IsLoading = false;
        });
    }

Comment: @waxingsatirical: You'd want to move the `IsLoading = false` outside the `Task.Run`, but otherwise that should work fine. Note that if `LoadData` is `async void`, then this will cause problems - if implementations need to be `async`, then the abstract method should return `Task`.